# how make post title from rtl to ltr in one post only in blogger

Tags: blogger, direction

I have blogger site in Arabic language so direction text is rtl and when I want to write post in English the direction of text is rtl like image below

[image]

so can I make it ltr in certain post like this image

[image]

I mean using both rtl and ltr so, when I use English the direction of text should be ltr and when I use Arabic the direction of text should be rtl

[my URL website](https://www.islamink.com)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `dir='auto'` should solve this

```html
<h1 class='entry-title' dir='auto'>{POST_TITLE}</h1>
```